# Why wxPython applications are slow to start?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there anyway to speedup start-up for wxPython? It takes usually around 5 seconds for the application to start on my Ubuntu machine, even when I write the most simple ones!

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
                frame = wx.Frame(None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Duplicate Detector", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,600 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                frame.Show(True)
                return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(redirect=False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The tiny bit of code above, takes some times to load.

Comment: Any code? They instantly load for me on both ubuntu and windows.

Comment: They usually load up faster than that for me on Windows. Maybe you should show a splash screen or something. If you have slow stuff in the program, like lots of database access or file reading, do that after it's loaded or in threads.

Comment: your code starts almost instantly for me on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython is a big package, and takes a non-trivial amount of time to load. Other toolkits may take less time, but the effort to port an app may not be worth it.

```
$ time python -c 'import wx'

real    0m1.646s
user    0m0.306s
sys     0m0.079s
```

Comment: Not really. Preloading the files doesn't help since the preloading will take the same amount of time, and you can't do the package setup until the application actually starts anyway.

Comment: time python -c "import wx": real 0m0.143s user 0m0.108s sys 0m0.020s